# websites ip address leading to different website

Tags: php, mysql, ip

so i was connecting to my database using php's following code

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("websiteIP/domainName", "username", "password", "databasename");
if(!$connect){
   echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
   echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
   echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
   exit;
}
```

and i got this error

> Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.
>
> Debugging errno: 1045
>
> Debugging error: Access denied for user
>   'username'@'www.365casino.online' (using password: YES)

Now the real confusing past is `www.365casino.online` is not my domain but i don't know why is it showing and it is blocking me access to connect to my database.

P.S. i have checked and the issue is not of username or password or databasename.

Comment: what is there in `websiteIP/domainName`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie there is my websites IP address e.g 192.168.0.20 and i have also tried putting my actual domain name e.g www.example.com

Comment: The hostname shown in the error message is what MySQL got back when doing a reverse DNS lookup of the IP address from which your website is connecting. Your site is probably hosted on the same server as that site. If you ping that site and your own website, does it show the same IP address?

Comment: @rickdenhaan when i ping that website i does not return any IP address, just gives error determining IP address.

Comment: @AliHassan could be a reused IP address, I'd check with your hosting provider (or if it's a VPS/dedicated server, with whoever's providing the network connection). But maybe someone else has a different idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the answer myself, it's very simple just use `localhost` in place of your website Domain Name or IP address. like,

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "databasename");
```